# CSS setup avoids upload popup to appear when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two setups for the same case (there is a fiddle for each one, basically it is about an HTML upload form):

1) In this one, the *id* of the `<body>` tag is set to 'product'. Here I have the right look and feel for the "Choose a file" button. However, when I click on it, it does not react by showing any pop-up for file selection (it only reacts on the "No file selected button" textfield).

https://jsfiddle.net/fvzw1woq/2/

2) Here, `<body>` does not have any id. The "Choose a file" button does not have the right look and feel, but it reacts well when clicking on it (as well as "No file selected button" textfield).

https://jsfiddle.net/nu2vt4gw/1/

**IMPORTANT:** The CSS Snippet is exactly the same for both fiddles.

I tried hard to know what is happening, but I can't know at all what the reason is. Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Code belongs here, you however may compliment your question with fiddle links.

Comment: Unless I have some kind of illness with my vision skills, fiddle links were included from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your first fiddle is z-index of an input file. check updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fvzw1woq/3/)

```
div.uploader input {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: right;
    cursor: default;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999999; // add this line
}
```

Comment: WOW, so fast, so good. Probably the reason is that due to z-index the overlapping design was removing the chance for the button to react. Thank you very much!!!